# How do you define the same autocomplete for multiple programs?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have the following line in my ~/.bashrc.

```
complete -W '$(cat $HOME/.config/autocomplete.list1 $HOME/.config/autocomplete.list2)' stream
```

I wasn't to use the same for another program called streama and streamb.  Is there a better way than typing the same definition two more times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append  `streama streamb` to your command.

See: `help complete`